# a catch-all route cuts before package routes (translations in my case) - Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5

I use https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-translation-manager
to handle translations in my app. 
The translation manager uses a route `translations` defined within the package.

### problem

I wanted to put a catch-all route at the end of my `Http/routes.php` file.

```
// http://laraveldaily.com/routes-file-redirect-everything-else-to-homepage/
Route::any('{query}', 
function() { return redirect('/'); })
->where('query', '.*');
```

### to do

Unfortunately the package route is now ignored. Is there any way to make both things work?

Comment: Try to load the `Barryvdh\TranslationManager\ManagerServiceProvider` before the `RouteServiceProvider` just change the order !

Comment: it worked. Thank you. 
If in your opinion your dirty hack deserves the rank of an accepted answer, you know what to do.

Comment: I think we need that, so people facing the same problem in the future will be able to spot it easily :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because your `catch-all` route is registered (in `RouteServiceProvider`) before the `translations` routes ( in `Barryvdh\TranslationManager\ManagerServiceProvider`). One possible solution is to change the order of these *Service Providers* in your `app.php`:

```
'providers' => [
    //........
    Barryvdh\TranslationManager\ManagerServiceProvider:class,
    App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
    //............
]
```